# Add a flag value to column based on previous value

Tags: r, flags

probably simple, but no nerves any more after hours of trial and error

My dataframe looks basically like this:

```
ID   Flag 
1    0 
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    0
```

Now I need to flag the rows following a "`value 1 row`" with a 1 aswell. without loosing the old flag and in the same column plus a new colum with only the newly flagged values. result should look like this:

```
ID   Flag Flag2
1    0    0 
2    0    0
3    1    0
4    1    1
5    0    0
6    1    0
7    1    0
8    1    1
```

help is very appreciated!

Comment: Please properly format code in your question. As it stands, it's hard to understand what you're after.

Comment: done, sorry first time here, many thanks to you all